# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null while inserting data through wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, pdo, insert

Im stuck here: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\wamp64\www\covid19-rdc\wp-content\plugins\cov19-drc-form\inclus\cdf-functions.php on line 431.

Im building a wordpress plugin that contains a registration form. But trying to insert data through my plugin, Im getting this message. I've read similar issues online but none of them is close to my case. Im to nez to php, so please help.

Here is my connexion:

```
require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'cnx_bdd.php';
```

And the rest of the code is here below:

```
//Connexion to the db in the connexion file

$host = "localhost";
$db   = "covid19rdc_db";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$charset = "utf8mb4";


try 
{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset", $user, $pass);
} 

catch (\PDOException $e) 
{
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

//This is the function that saves the data

```
function save_data()
{
    if ( isset($_POST['btnEnregistrer'] ) ) 
    {




        // sanitize entries

        global $nomPat, $postnomPat, $prenomPat, $datenaisPat, $sexePat, $etatcivil, $nationalite_ID, $telPat, $emailPat, $domicilePat, $commune_ID, $ville, $paysvisites, $date_entree, $point_entree, $contactUrgence, $emailUrgence, $telUrgence, $catdeclarant, $fonction_agent, $commentaires;         



            $nomPat         =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['nomPat'] );
            $postnomPat     =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['postnomPat'] );
            $prenomPat      =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['prenomPat'] ); 
            $datenaisPat    =   $_POST['datenaisPat'];
            $sexePat        =   $_POST['sexePat'];
            $etatcivil      =   $_POST['etatcivil'];
            $nationalite_ID =   $_POST['nationalite_ID'];
            $telPat         =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['telPat'] );                
            $emailPat       =   sanitize_email( $_POST['emailPat'] ); 
            $domicilePat    =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['domicilePat'] );
            $commune_ID     =   $_POST['commune_ID'];
            $ville          =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['ville'] );
            $paysvisites    =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['paysvisites'] );
            $date_entree        =   $_POST['date_entree'];
            $point_entree   =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['point_entree'] );
            $contactUrgence =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['contactUrgence'] );                
            $emailUrgence   =   sanitize_email( $_POST['emailUrgence'] );
            $telUrgence     =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['telUrgence'] );
            $catdeclarant   =   $_POST['catdeclarant'];
            $fonction_agent     =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['fonction_agent'] );
            $commentaires   =   sanitize_text_field( $_POST['commentaires'] );



            $nomPat         =   $_POST['nomPat'] ;
            $postnomPat     =   $_POST['postnomPat'] ;
            $prenomPat      =   $_POST['prenomPat'] ; 
            $datenaisPat    =   $_POST['datenaisPat'];
            $sexePat        =   $_POST['sexePat'];
            $etatcivil      =   $_POST['etatcivil'];
            $nationalite_ID =   $_POST['nationalite_ID'];
            $telPat         =   $_POST['telPat'] ;              
            $emailPat       =   $_POST['emailPat'] ; 
            $domicilePat    =   $_POST['domicilePat'] ;
            $commune_ID     =   $_POST['commune_ID'];
            $ville          =   $_POST['ville'] ;
            $paysvisites    =   $_POST['paysvisites'] ;
            $date_entree    =   $_POST['date_entree'];
            $point_entree   =   $_POST['point_entree'] ;
            $contactUrgence =   $_POST['contactUrgence'] ;              
            $emailUrgence   =   $_POST['emailUrgence'] ;
            $telUrgence     =   $_POST['telUrgence'] ;
            $catdeclarant   =   $_POST['catdeclarant'];
            $fonction_agent     =   $_POST['fonction_agent'] ;
            $commentaires   =   $_POST['commentaires'] ;





        // insert data




        $sql = "INSERT INTO cov_patient(NomPatient, PostnomPatient, PrenomPatient, DateNaisPatient, SexePatient, EtatCivil, Nationalite_ID, TelPatient, EmailPatient, DomicilePatient, Commune_ID, Ville, PaysVisites, DateEntree, PointEntree, ContactUrgence, EmailUrgence, TelUrgence, CatDeclarant, FonctionAgent) VALUES (:nomPat, :postnomPat, :prenomPat, :datenaisPat, :sexePat, :etatcivil, :nationalite_ID, :telPat, :emailPat, :domicilePat, :commune_ID, :ville, :paysvisites, :date_entree, :point_entree, :contactUrgence, :emailUrgence, :telUrgence, :catdeclarant, :fonction_agent, :commentaires)";

        $req = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        $req-> execute(array(
                        ":nomPat"           => $nomPat, 
                        ":postnomPat"       => $postnomPat, 
                        ":prenomPat"        => $prenomPat,
                        ":datenaisPat"      => $datenaisPat, 
                        ":sexePat"          => $sexePat , 
                        ":etatcivil"        => $etatcivil , 
                        ":nationalite_ID"   => $nationalite_ID , 
                        ":telPat"           => $telPat , 
                        ":emailPat"         => $emailPat , 
                        ":domicilePat"      => $domicilePat , 
                        ":commune_ID"       => $commune_ID , 
                        ":ville"            => $ville ,
                        ":paysvisites"      => $paysvisites ,
                        ":date_entree"      => $date_entree ,
                        ":point_entree"     => $point_entree ,
                        ":contactUrgence"   => $contactUrgence ,
                        ":emailUrgence"     => $emailUrgence ,
                        ":telUrgence"       => $telUrgence ,
                        ":catdeclarant"     => $catdeclarant ,
                        ":fonction_agent"   => $fonction_agent ,
                        ":commentaires"     => $commentaires

                    )
                );

        echo 'Success.';   

    }



    else
    {
        //call the form creation function

        mon_formulaire_covid19(
            $nomPat, 
            $postnomPat, 
            $prenomPat, 
            $datenaisPat, 
            $sexePat, 
            $etatcivil, 
            $nationalite_ID, 
            $telPat, 
            $emailPat, 
            $domicilePat, 
            $commune_ID, 
            $ville,
            $paysvisites,
            $date_entree,
            $point_entree,
            $contactUrgence,
            $emailUrgence,
            $telUrgence,
            $catdeclarant,
            $fonction_agent,
            $commentaires
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the $pdo variable [scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

What you need to do is pass the $pdo to the function.

Assuming that all your code is located in cnx_bdd.php your `save_data()` function will need a parameter, like this `save_data($pdo) {...}`.

Now when calling the save_data function you can pass it the connection handle ($pdo) and everything will work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

when you are declaring $pdo it's in global scope...

```
try 
{
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset", $user, $pass);
} 

catch (\PDOException $e) 
{
  throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

but here inside this function you don't have reference to $pdo object...

```
function save_data()
{
...........
$req = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

either you can declare your `$pdo` connection inside `save_data()` function or use `global $pdo` inside your `save_data()` function

Solution 1 :

```
function save_data()
{
...........
//Connexion to the db in the connexion file

$host = "localhost";
$db   = "covid19rdc_db";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$charset = "utf8mb4";

try 
{
   $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset", $user, $pass);
} 

catch (\PDOException $e) 
{
   throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

$req = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

Solution 2 :

```
function save_data()
{
...........
global $pdo; //access $pdo db connection object
$req = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```